# Calculating the convex conjugate of the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\log \sum_{k=1}^n e^{a_k\cdot x+b_k}\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

The convex conjugate also known as Legendre–Fenchel transformation of a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ is function $f^\ast:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ definite by 
$$
f^{\ast}(x^\ast)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{ x\cdot x^\ast -f(x)\}
$$
Let $\{a_k\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_k\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ numerical sequences such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{a_k\cdot x+b_k}<\infty$. Let the function
$
f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\log \sum_{k=1}^n e^{a_k\cdot x+b_k}\right).
$
By a simple calculations and by [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) we prove that $f(x)$ is convex. Then Legendre-Fenchel transformation is well defined.

> **Question.** What is the convex conjugate of the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\log \sum_{k=1}^n e^{a_k\cdot x+b_k}\right)$?

A more explicit way, I would calculate the supremum below
\begin{align}
f^{\ast}(x^\ast)
=
&
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}
\left\{
x\cdot x^\ast
+
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\log \sum_{k=1}^n e^{a_k\cdot x+b_k}\right)
\right\}.
\\
\end{align}

Comment: I'm confused about the scaling here.  Since $L(x)=\sum_{k>0}\exp(a_kx+b_k)<\infty$, doesn't the argument of the $\log$ have a finite limit, and $\log(\ldots)/n\to 0 ?$

Comment: @kimchilover This depends on the values ​​of $a_k$ and $b_k$. We can have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0<k\leq n}\exp(a_kx+b_k)=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n)\sum_{0<k\leq n}\exp(a_kx+b_k)<\infty$.

Comment: But  your division by $n$ happens *outside* the logarithm.  So I am still as perplexed as ever.

Comment: @kimchilover Oops, I wanted to say $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0<k\leq n}\exp(a_kx+b_k)=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{0<k\leq n}\exp(a_kx+b_k)\right]^{1/n}<\infty$.

Comment: I get it now.  The $a_k$ and $b_k$ also depend on $n$, sort of suppressed in the notation.  Can't your $\sum_k \exp(a_k x + b_k)$ be the moment generating functions of any discrete random variable taking on $n$ values? Such as binomially distributed with parameters $p$ and $n-1$, for which the $\log(\cdot)/n$ limit recovers the log m.g.f. of the Bernouilli summand, yielding a different answer for each possible $p?$  So are you really asking, how does $f^*(x)$ depend on the sequences of $a$ and $b$ sequences?